# intellisense menu crash in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am using vs2008 and developing a windows application . Suddenly , the intellisense menu does not suggesting the controls which i was designed on the designing page . i just rebuild , restarted even it's not working . Found other forms in the same project working fine . Am i done anything wrong with the designer file ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=26662